# How to make controller wait for service to return a value and how to access the returned value in controller?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angularjs-scope, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

I am new to **angularjs**. I am having trouble in accessing **value that is returned from angularjs service in its controller**. 
**Following is the code in controller:**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('AdminTaskCtrl', function ($scope, Search) {
    $scope.buildEnquiry = function (collegeId, ) {
        Search.getIdByEmail(collegeId).then ( function ( result ) {
            $scope.uId = result;
            console.log($scope.uId);
        });
    };
});//controller ends here
```

**And the code in Search service is as follows:**

```
'use strict';
           app.factory('Search',function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope) {
                          var simpleuser = "";
                          getIdByEmail: function(counsellorEmail) {
                          var collegeuserArray = ($firebase(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+"abc/def/")).$asArray());
                          collegeuserArray.$loaded(function(collegeuserArray) {
                              for(var i=0; i<collegeuserArray.length; i++) 
                              {
                                if((collegeuserArray[i].$value) == counsellorEmail)
                                {
                                     simpleuser = collegeuserArray.$keyAt(collegeuserArray[i]);
                                     console.log(simpleuser);
                                     return simpleuser;
                                }
                              }
                          }, function(error) {
                              console.error("Error:", error);
                          });
                    }
                  };     
            );//service ends here.
```

**When the code executes it gives error for .then function as fallows:**

**TypeError: undefined is not a function** and value in controller is not accessed.

Please help.

Comment: you must implement ``$q`` into your factory, check this : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Hey Deblaton Jean-Philippe, I am having trouble in implementing $q in my factory. Could u please guide me through the process...!! ?

Comment: what is $firebase, and why do you return it first? Do you sometimes enter your "for" loop?

Comment: actually firebase is my nosql database which contains my specific set of values that I need. I am getting the values from firebase, but the problem is I am not able to return the value in the controller. [.then] in controller gives the error that i have mentioned in the question. And yes I enter the loop for every value I get from firebase.

Comment: excute this : ``var something = Search.getIdByEmail(collegeId)`` and tell me what is inside ``something``. btw, I don't get why the code continues after ``return ($firebase(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+"abc/def/")).$asArray());``

Comment: How exactly does `getIdByEmail: function() {...}` compile here? I'm fairly sure this syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
'use strict';
       app.factory('Search',function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope, $q) {
                      var simpleuser = "";
                      getIdByEmail: function(counsellorEmail) {
                      var deferred = $q.defer();
                      var collegeUserArray = ($firebase(new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL+"abc/def/")).$asArray());
                      collegeUserArray.$loaded(function(collegeUserArray) {
                          for(var i=0; i<collegeUserArray.length; i++) 
                          {
                            if((collegeUserArray[i].$value) == counsellorEmail)
                            {
                                 simpleUser = collegeUserArray.$keyAt(collegeUserArray[i]);
                                 console.log(simpleUser);
                                 //return simpleUser;
                                 deferred.resolve(simpleUser);
                            }
                          }
                      }, function(error) {
                          console.error("Error:", error);
                          deferred.reject(error);
                      });
                      return deferred.promise;
                }
              };     
        );
```

And your controller

```
'use strict';
app.controller('AdminTaskCtrl', function ($scope, Search) {
  $scope.buildEnquiry = function (collegeId, ) {
    Search.getIdByEmail(collegeId).then ( function ( result ) {
        $scope.uId = result;
        console.log($scope.uId);
    }, function(error){
        //If an error happened, handle it here
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks Deblaton Jean-Philippe. The code worked for me.

Comment: The syntax here also appears invalid, copied from the original question. Also, $loaded already returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, `$loaded` [returns a promise](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded), so the simplest answer here would be to return it from your service instead of bothering with $q and all these other things.

It does seem like the whole premise here is flawed and that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). It seems like several hacks intended to subvert the intended usage of these libs, and like a good, solid read of the [Angular walkthrough](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_01) and the [AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html) would save a lot of pain and needless complexity here.

The use of factory here is a subversion and heavily coupled. The syntax is invalid and wouldn't compile. And ultimately, the goal is to add a search method to the synchronized array returned from AngularFire, which should be done with $extendFactory.

```
app.factory('firebaseRef', function(FIREBASE_URL) {
   return function(path) {
      var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
      if( path ) { ref = ref.child(path); }
      return ref;
   }
});

app.factory('SearchableArray', function($firebase, $FirebaseArray) {
   var ArrayWithSearch = $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory({
     searchByEmail: function(emailAddress) {
        var res = null;
        for(var i=0, len=this.$list.length; i < len; i++ ) {
           if( this.$list[i].email === emailAddress ) {
              res = this.$list[i];
              break;
           }
        }
        return res;
     }
   });

   return function(ref) {
      return $firebase(ref, {arrayFactory: ArrayWithSearch}).$asArray();      
   }
});

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, SearchableArray, firebaseRef) {
   $scope.data = SearchableArray( firebaseRef('abc/def') );

   $scope.search = function(email) {
      console.log( $scope.data.searchByEmail(email) );
   };
});
```